# Adding a HABTM as a registration in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

- I have `Users` and `Courses`.
- I have a `users` table, and a `courses` table.
- I also have a `course_memberships` table with `id |
  course_id | user_id`
- I have the appropriate `hasmany` relationship
  for `courses` and `users` to relate to `CourseMembership`

But I have no idea how to create that relationship using a button on the front end. Something like a `public function register()` on the `Courses` controller that would put the `Auth User ID` in the `user_id field`, and the `course id` in the `course_id` field to form the relationship.

I know it was a wall of text, but I figured a description of the issue may be more helpful than an endless scroll of code.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method to save to the CourseMembership model within the Courses Controller. Something like this would work.

```
public function register($course_id){
    $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$data = array(
    course_id => $course_id,
    user_id => $user_id;
);
if($this->Courses->CourseMembership->save($data)){
    $this->Session->setFlash('Registered');
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
else{
    $this->Session->setFlash('Could not register');
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

}

This way, when people go to /Courses/register/1, it would register them for the course with the ID of 1.

Then when you do a find on the User, the data would be in $user['CourseMembership']